como consumo mi web services ASMX en un proyecto web api
Tengo un error por que estoy trayendo el esquema de una tabla de una base de datos, y como viene en XML lo convierto a DataTable para escribir los datos que tengo y enviarlo, como es Soap el web services no me acepta un data table que es el que recibe el método del web services, necesito convertirlo tal cual como llego el esquema pero con datos para enviarlos a la base de datos y que el método que escribe me los acepte
        DataSet theDataSet = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            TraerTablaResponseTraerTablaResult tabla = accesoDatosSoapClient.TraerTabla("Aplicaciones", 0);
            string nombre = tabla.Any1.InnerXml.ToString();
            StringReader theReader = new StringReader(nombre);
            theDataSet.ReadXmlSchema(theReader);
            theDataSet.Tables[0].Columns.Remove("id");
            theDataSet.Tables[0].Columns.Remove("rowOrder");


            DataRow newRow = theDataSet.Tables[0].NewRow();
            newRow[0] = 2;
            newRow[1]=nombreApp;
            newRow[2]=descripcion;
            newRow[3]=version;
            newRow[5]="1";
            theDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(newRow);

            StringWriter write = new StringWriter();
            theDataSet.Tables[0].WriteXml(write,XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema,false);

            InsertarTablaTable ObjetoInsertar = new InsertarTablaTable();
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(write.ToString());
            ObjetoInsertar.Any1=doc.DocumentElement;

            write = new StringWriter();
            theDataSet.WriteXml(write, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
            XmlElement rootElement = doc.DocumentElement;
            doc.LoadXml(write.ToString());
            ObjetoInsertar.Any = rootElement;






            accesoDatosSoapClient.InsertarTabla(ObjetoInsertar,"Aplicaciones",0);
           


puedes mostrar los errores que te genera, y donde lo hace, ya que  es necesario que proveas todo lo necesario para entender el problema

buenas. Es necesario que proveas todo lo necesario para poder comprender los problemas, errores, librerías, sectores del código donde se producen los errores, etc.

Un SOAP no se trabaja leyendo/escribiendo un XML, es que carece de todo sentido. C# y visual studio cuentan con todas las herramientas necesarias para crear y/o consumir un SOAP sin tener que preocuparse del XML

Es que yo cree un web services desde visual studio, y funciona perfectamente lo que hace es leer y escribir en una base de datos.
Actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto con react y el utiliza api rest para comunicarse, basicamente el ".server" y genera el proyecto con visual studio,leo y traigo esquemas de las tablas pero me los devuelve xML y accedo a ellos por medio de la propiedad Any1 y lo que tiene se lo paso a un DataTable para insertar datos, cuando la tabla ya tiene datos utilizo un metodo del web services para insertar una tabla. ese bloque de codigo que pase es esa parte cuando atrapo, convierto y añado, por ultimo le convierto  a xml y se la paso a el metodo pero no inserta datos.
este es el metodo donde utilzo el web services,
    public DataTable CrearAplicacion(string nombreApp, decimal version, string descripcion)
    {
        DataSet theDataSet = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            TraerTablaResponseTraerTablaResult tabla = accesoDatosSoapClient.TraerTabla("Aplicaciones", 0);
            string nombre = tabla.Any1.InnerXml.ToString();
            StringReader theReader = new StringReader(nombre);
            theDataSet.ReadXmlSchema(theReader);
            theDataSet.Tables[0].Columns.Remove("id");
            theDataSet.Tables[0].Columns.Remove("rowOrder");


            DataRow newRow = theDataSet.Tables[0].NewRow();
            newRow[0] = 2;
            newRow[1]=nombreApp;
            newRow[2]=descripcion;
            newRow[3]=version;
            newRow[5]="1";
            theDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(newRow);

            StringWriter write = new StringWriter();
            theDataSet.Tables[0].WriteXml(write,XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema,false);

            InsertarTablaTable ObjetoInsertar = new InsertarTablaTable();
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(write.ToString());
            ObjetoInsertar.Any1=doc.DocumentElement;

            write = new StringWriter();
            theDataSet.WriteXml(write, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
            XmlElement rootElement = doc.DocumentElement;
            doc.LoadXml(write.ToString());
            






            accesoDatosSoapClient.InsertarTabla(ObjetoInsertar,"Aplicaciones",0);
           



        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        return theDataSet.Tables[0];

    }

